# Chart js display empty plot

Tags: chart.js

I am using chart.js .Bar() charts.

However, on some conditions there may be no data in the system. Short of creating empty (dummy) datasets, can I somehow make chartjs draw an empty plot?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you have done so far

Comment: how can I create an empty grid chart for line chart?

Comment: @zazu Have you tried giving chart.js an empty array as data ? Does it suit your needs ?

Comment: @bviale nothing is rendered

Comment: @zazu see if it renders something with the jsfiddle in my answer

Answer (score 8):

Edit: I edited the post to show horizontal lines of an empty graph as @zazu asked for it

In this sample, I set up a Chart.js line graph, providing a first dataset with data (in order to scale the grid vertical axis and make the horizontal lines visible), and a second one with empty data. This results in an empty graph, but with the full grid visible:

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [
    // invisible dataset
    {
        label: "",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.0)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        // change this data values according to the vertical scale
        // you are looking for 
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    // your real chart here
    {
        label: "My dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: []
    }
]
};

var options = {
    animation: false,
    ///Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
    scaleShowGridLines : true,
    //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    showTooltips: false
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yn3Ljefk/3/).

Comment: I also need horizontal lines in the grid. I do not see them here.

Comment: this is great! Much better than the answer I have already found myself. I used the scale (this is responsible for grid lines) to draw such graph.

Comment: The solution was so easy I am even a bit frustrated that I have bidden so much :))

Comment: Easy but not beautiful, it looks like a hack, maybe it was possible to do better by creating a new type of graph... If you have time and you look for a better solution I recommend you to look for overriding line chart

Comment: how do I force the Y-axis to have values going from 0 to 100 by manipulating the data?

Comment: @Jorrex By setting a 0 and a 100 as the min and max value in the array : data: [**0**, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, **100**]

Answer (score 0):

If you're fetching data from API, you can handle it as follows:

```js
if (res.data) {
  chartData = {
    labels: getChartLabels(res.data),
    datasets: [
      //set your data set
    ],
  };
  //other assignments
} else {
  chartData.datasets.forEach((item) => (item.data = []));
}
```

It'll empty the dataset's data list when there are no records.

**Update**

In my case, I had to initialize the empty state of chartData. Something like this:

```js
const powerChartData = {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Max",
      backgroundColor: "#0086C9",
      borderColor: "#0086C9",
      data: [],
      fill: false,
    },
    {
      label: "Average",
      backgroundColor: "#32D583",
      borderColor: "#32D583",
      data: [],
      fill: false,
    },
  ],
};
```

Later, I just need to fill in `powerChartData.datasets[].data`